# Explainer, Refiner and Illuminator aren't internationalized

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, portuguese-stackoverflow

Just noticed.

> [image]

To be translated?

Comment: @lostsock good, you can post it as a new bug :)

Comment: Derp. Wait, how do you say Derp in Portuguese?

Comment: @TimPost [it's still derp](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/derp) :)

Comment: @Tim *I*? I don't speak portuguese :D